# socket client don't work on Kali

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault, client-server

I'm trying to make a simple client-server program, but always get Segmentation fault on client. I've checked IP address, port, tried many alternative solutions but non worked for me.

> The server code:

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        int sock,mysock;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        char buff[1024];

     char s[256];

    if (!gethostname(s, sizeof s))
        {
            printf ("Machine: %s\n", s);
            {
                struct hostent *host= gethostbyname(s);

                if (host  != NULL)
                {
                    struct in_addr **adr;

                    for (adr = (struct in_addr **)host->h_addr_list; *adr; adr++)
                    {
                        printf("IP : %s\n", inet_ntoa(**adr));
                    }
                }
            }
        } 


        /*creation du socket*/
        sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        if (sock<0)
        {
            perror("creation de socket echouer\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        server.sin_family=AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port=5000;

        if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server,sizeof(server)) < 0) 
             {perror("ERROR on binding");
              exit(1);}

        /*listen for just 1 connection*/
        listen(sock,1);
        mysock=accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)0,0);
        if (mysock==-1)
        {
            perror("accept failed");
            exit(1);
        }




        write(mysock,"you are connected to: my server\n",55);
        read(mysock,buff,sizeof(buff));
        printf("%s\n",buff);
        gets();
        close(sock);
        close(mysock);


        return 0;
    }
```

> The client code:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct hostent *hp;
    char buff[1024];

    /*creation du socket*/
    sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (sock<0)
    {
        perror("creation de socket echouer\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (hp == NULL) {
        perror("ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("0\n");
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.1.1");
    server.sin_port=htons(5000);
printf("1\n" );
    if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)<0))
    {
        perror("connection failed");
        exit(1);
    }printf("2\n");
    read(sock,buff,sizeof(buff));
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    write(sock,"thanks for accepting me\n",25);

    system("PAUSE");
    close(sock);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Are you passing argument to your program.

Comment: Run your program with arguments.  It will start showing errors

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If the *specific* questions arise feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you got segmentation fault on client in consequence of this line:

```
hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
```

The way to get segfault here is to pass a `NULL`-pointer. So you do this every time that you run your client without an command line argument.
P.S. Don't quite understand, why do you need it at all.

---

Notes:

- It would be nice to fix the obvious missteps as e.g. Steffen mentioned. Also initialize buffers something like this: `char buff[1024] = {0};` to avoid trouble. And check the return value of functions to see whether errors occurred.
- From [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname):

> The gethostbyname*() and gethostbyaddr*() functions are obsolete.
>   Applications should use getaddrinfo(3) and getnameinfo(3) instead.

---

**EDIT**:
So the working code for your client can be such:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int sock;
    ssize_t bytes;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char buff[1024] = {0}, tosend[] = "thanks for accepting me";
    /*
    struct hostent *hp;
    if(argv[1]) {
        hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
        if (hp == NULL) {
            perror("gethostbyname");
            return;
        }
        // something with hp
    }
   */
    /*creation du socket*/
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.1.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(5000);
    printf("1\n");
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof server) < 0) {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("2\n");
    if ((bytes = read(sock, buff, sizeof(buff) - 1)) < 0) {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    } else if (! bytes)
        puts("finished");
      else
        printf("%s\n", buff);
    if (write(sock, tosend, sizeof tosend) < 0)
        perror("write");

    return 0;
 }
```

If you use the commented lines, pass some command line argument when running client like `./client somename`

**ALSO** on server side you should change at least the following things:

- remove or change `gets()` call, because it requires an argument
- set port number like `htons(5000)`

Comment: Another way to get a segfault is to access a non-existent element of the `argv` array. You don't need to initialize network buffers.

Comment: @EJP Perhaps, but not sure. I can't provoke segfault such way.
As for buffers. There is a case where an uninitialized buffer points to garbage left by the previous function on stack. Thus if now it points e.g. to "AAAAAA\0" and you read 3 bytes from server like "BBB" we can get something like "BBBAAA\0" as a string. So I said that would be nice to initialize buffers.

Comment: please guys can someone correct my code and post it?

Answer (score 1):

There could be more problems but this one is definitely wrong:

```
your code:   if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)<0))
correct:     if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server))<0)
                                                                       ^^^^
```

Comment: hi, thanks i did notice that after posting problem is can't connect